# CATransform3D around all axis

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation

I'm trying to create a kind of 'flip' animation that rotates a UIView 180 degrees around each axis, however, I am having trouble getting the desired effect. Here's what I've got so far:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{     
        CATransform3D tX= CATransform3DIdentity;
        tX.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
        CATransform3D tY= CATransform3DIdentity;
        tY.m34 = 1.0 / -500;
        CATransform3D tZ= CATransform3DIdentity;
        tZ.m34 = 1.0 / -500;

        tX = CATransform3DRotate(tX, M_PI, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        tY = CATransform3DRotate(tY, M_PI, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        tZ = CATransform3DRotate(tZ, M_PI, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

        self.flipView.layer.transform = CATransform3DConcat(tX, CATransform3DConcat(tY, tZ));            
    }
```

This however, doesn't appear to perform any animations, as if they are canceling eachother out. Seems like this should be a pretty straightforward task, but I can't seem to figure out how to combine each of those 3 animation conditions. Any help greatly appreciated! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating by a half-rotation (180° or π radians) about each of the three axes does, in total, result in no change (the concatenation of the three rotation transforms results in the identity transform).

Try rotating about just one axis to see what that does.

Comment: thanks that was helpful. I was thinking it would perform the animation even if the end point was the same as the start point - but apparently not

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the `UIView` animations and probably even the `CABasicAnimation`s look at the start and end states and figure out what to do based solely on those.  There may well be another animation mechanism, though, that works like you were thinking.